# Sony Vaio incompatible battery

Tags: laptop, battery, sony-vaio

I have had this laptop for over a year now and it has just come up with an error message that states:

- The installed battery may not be properly connected to the computer or may not be compatible with the computer.  Click OK to enter Hibernation mode.

The battery is connected to the laptop properly and it is the battery I received with the laptop.  How can I disable the computer from going into hibernation mode or fix this problem?

Comment: misspelled "vaio"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your battery is probably ready to be replaced (it's showing 'incompatible', because it's failing); notebook batteries have an expected life of about one year (according to the manufacturers).

If you still have warranty remaining you may want to contact Sony, or the place you bought it from, and figure out possible replacement options.

If you want to know how to disable hibernation, you'll want to provide information on the OS you're using.

Comment: sorry i have resolved the problem it has to do with a windows update corrupting some componant in my computer and just had to stop a certian item from starting on boot